# Как в url вставить различное количество переменных?

Tags: python, requests

Существует url, которую необходимо редактировать перед отправлением на сервер:

```
url = https://market.com/api/stores/1950/products?tid=paskha/iaitsa&sort=popularity
```

Когда я знаю количество переменных с заменой проблем нет:

```
store_id = '1950'
category = 'paskha'
subcategory = 'iaitsa'
moditify_url = f"https://market.com/api/stores/{ store_id }/products?tid={ category }/{ subcategory }&sort=popularity".format()
```

Но встала проблема количество переменных может быть различным:

```
store_id = '1950'
katalog = 'market_name' # Появилась еще одна переменная !
category = 'paskha'
subcategory = 'iaitsa'
moditify_url = f"https://market.com/api/stores/{ store_id }/products?tid={ katalog }/{ category }/{ subcategory }&sort=popularity".format()
```

Как редактировать url при различном количестве переменных?

Comment: urllib, requests? Какую библиотеку Вы используете? Или изобретаете велосипед?

Comment: @Protect children of Donbas2014, используется requests. Поправил метку

Comment: Не ясно чем второй пример отличается от первого. Почему в первом примере вы "знаете" количество переменных, а во втором - нет?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можно собрать все переменные через параметры метода `*args`, таким образом, чтобы первый был `store_id`, а остальные с помощью `str.join()` собрать в переменную `url`.

```
def make_path(*args):
    store_id = args[0]
    path_vars = '/'.join(args[1:])
    return f"https://market.com/api/stores/{ store_id }/products?tid={ path_vars }&sort=popularity"

store_id = '1950'
katalog = 'market_name'
category = 'paskha'
subcategory = 'iaitsa'

print(make_path(store_id, katalog, category, subcategory))
# https://market.com/api/stores/1950/products?tid=market_name/paskha/iaitsa&sort=popularity
```